# viewing the largest file in the directory using linux?

Tags: linux, unix

1.How to view the largest file in the directory using linux commands.

2.As i followed the following command ls -lh.

3.Is any other way to use the linux commands to view the largest file inside the directory with its size in human readable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

> $ find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%s %p\n'|sort -nr|head

It will give you the top 10 in your directory. And if you just want the largest one:

> $ find . -type f | xargs ls -1S | head -n 1

With its "parameters/attributes" (**size**, permissions, creation date & time):

> $ find . -type f | xargs ls -lS | head -n 1

And if youy want to use `ls` without `find` try:

> $ ls -S . | head -1

Comment: use of S and . @Idos

Comment: Sorry..am not aware of x and X@Idos

Comment: @welcomedata you are not aware of xargs? It's very easy, Google and read about them. It solved your question though right?

Comment: AM aware of small terms.it used to combine the commands@Idos

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -Slh | tail +2 | head -1
```

which uses `ls` to list your files in size order, long format with human readable sizes.  `tail +2` removes the first line of your output which is a total size and `head` gives you the largest file.

Comment: Can you tell me the need of tail in this comment@Neil Masson

Comment: `ls` gives me `total 59464` followed by `-rw-r--r--@  1 nmasson  staff    23M 25 Nov 03:43 gc.log`.  The `tail` says start at the second line, skipping the total line.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question using this command:

```
ls -Slh | head -2
```

This lists by size and selects the first two results.